# Atsar type resource monitor for Windows?

Tags: windows-server-2008, performance-monitoring

Does anyone know of any nice, simple system performance monitoring tools for a Windows 2008 RC2 server?  I come from a Linux world where Atsar would fulfill the job easily, and was looking for something simple like that.

Windows Reliability and Performance Monitor is too big and bulky, same with something like Splunk; I'm just want Atsar on Windows.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Super simple:
Right-click taskbar -> Start Task Manager -> Performance Tab

Slightly more info:
As above then click 'Resource Monitor'

Individual performance traces:
Start -> Run -> Perfmon -> Performance Monitor -> Right click 'add counters'

I don't think it gets much simper than that.

Comment: I'm not really interested in seeing the current information, I want to log performance information dumped periodically into a file so I can go back and make conclusions about the state of the system between hours of X and Y three weeks ago.  It also needs to be easily parsed.